# Displaying pictures in a gridview

Tags: android

Hi everyone I'm trying to display some images using a GridView. However I'm getting an error when I import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener that says that main cannot be resolved or is not a field. My code is below:

```
import import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
//Error here: main cannot be resolved or is not field

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.photogrid);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    } 
}

package com.newapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {

        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,

    };
}
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error? Any help would much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably unrelated to the import, I'd guess it is complaining about this: `R.layout.main`.  Is this a layout you defined?  You need to import the correct R file, most likely the one generated in your package: com.newapp.R?

Also, I assume that extra import at the beginning is a copy error?

Comment: Yes, you are right about the the extra import at the beginning is a copy error. Thank you very much for the help, Mayra. That answer helped me a lot.